# RTP streaming with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtp

I am trying to use rtp streaming using ffmpeg. I am taking input from pulseaudio and creating an rtp stream.
i.e. 
ffmpeg -re -f pulse -ac 2 -i SOURCE -ac 2 -acodec libmp3lame -re -f rtp rtp://192.168.1.4:70000

this is the sdp output that I get.

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.4
a=tool:libavformat 54.20.100^M
m=audio 7000 RTP/AVP 14^M
```

Now when I play this SDP from the same machine it runs.
But when I try to play it from other machines in the lan, it doesn't run.
For eg. using mplayer I get - Can't get stream info - error.

What is going wrong here?

Or should I be using some other server for streaming?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to superuser or elsewhere. There's no programming here.

Answer (score 6):

Your RTP IP range is not related to the IPs on your LAN and needs to be in the range of
`224.0.0.0` – `239.255.255.255`.  You also cannot use a port larger than `65535`.

```
ffmpeg -re -f pulse -ac 2 -i SOURCE -ac 2 -acodec libmp3lame -re -f rtp rtp://224.1.2.3:7000
```